# Apache 2.2: Restrict access via basic authentication generally - but NOT ON a server with a specific IP or domain WITHOUT VirtualHosts

Tags: apache, authentication, basic-authentication

Is it possible to restrict access via basic authentication generally, but not on a server that has a specific IP or domain name - without the use of virtual-hosts (and no use of Satisfy) ?

Addition: htpasswd can't be used as the solution.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a htpassword? You can restrict users at a basic level (username and password) using just a few lines. It shouldn't make a difference if your server has a dynamic IP, and you don't need virtual hosts.

[This generator makes it pretty simple](http://www.htaccesstools.com/htpasswd-generator/)

I hope this is the solution you need!

Comment: forgot to say, that i dont want to use a .htpasswd file - at least not many of them - and i do not think there is a solution without the use of satisfy within that context